# warning message while import data into R

Tags: r, excel

i am a newbie in R. need some help and advice regarding basic in R.
could all of u please help me with my error. i'm trying to import data into R from excel.

my data from excel is as follow:

```
psl.Pascal    tos.K          ua          va
    1      100828.2 300.6350 -2.90855289 -5.04159784
    2      100865.4 300.6375 -1.97473240 -3.88418388
    3      100781.0 301.3094 -1.22099233 -2.78284335
    4      100842.8 302.0707 -0.33391580 -2.04903889
```

while my coding:

```
 setwd("D:/Saved documents/research/data/msia_RCP_4.5")
 getwd()
 malaysia<-read.table("msia_RCP_4.5_CSIR045.csv",header=T, sep=",")
 malaysia
```

as i run my coding, i get the result as shown below:

```
> setwd("D:/Saved documents/research/data/msia_RCP_4.5")
> getwd()
[1] "D:/Saved documents/research/data/msia_RCP_4.5"
> malaysia<-read.table("msia_RCP_4.5_CSIR045.csv",header=T, sep=",")
   Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'msia_RCP_4.5_CSIR045.csv': No such file or directory
> malaysia
Error: object 'malaysia' not found
```

what does it means by file "rt"?

Comment: There is a `read.csv` function which uses the defaults you set in `read.table`.  You could also run `list.files(pattern="*.csv")` which should list any csv files in your current working directory to make sure the file is named right.

Comment: owh i see...thnk u very much..i get the idea already and problem solved..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the wrong file name or directory.

Try the following command, if it says FALSE then your file is not in your working directory ("D:/Saved documents/research/data/msia_RCP_4.5")

```
setwd("D:/Saved documents/research/data/msia_RCP_4.5")
'msia_RCP_4.5_CSIR045.csv' %in% list.files()
```

Check out `list.files()` to see the files that are your working directory (thanks @ben-bolker)

Comment: this is probably on the right track, but you could give more helpful ideas -- e.g. (1) use `file.choose()`; (2) use `list.files()` to see what's in the working directory

Comment: thnk u very much..the idea really help me